# angular6 form input value not right when dynamic close tab

Tags: angular, angular6

I put a child-component which has form in tab, but found that when I close tab, the child-component form value was changed to the delete tab, but the span value was correct. really strange. is a bug?

this is my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wca3px)

the steps: 
1. add two tab;
2. close the first 'New Tab'
3. then found that form input value wrong as the below pic

[image]

Comment: this is not a bug the case is values will be bind but for the input you have used formcontrol and it will be only call in ngoninint means the first time when the form loads and will assingn a values after the changes happen to that varilbe it wont call ngoninit it will call ngOnChanges(according to angular life cycle hooks) so use your binding method inside ngOnChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngOnChanges` instead of  `ngOnInit` for your child component. You will get expected result.

Comment: OnInit works when component is initialised. You are first creating new tab(Initialising component)  and then updating binding value. Now your binding value is updated, but `this.validateForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.buyer.name, [Validators.required]]
    });` is done only once so your input value will not update